# Why do my uploaded files not exist in my filesystem and are not returned by my PHP commands?

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm having trouble creating a form that will upload and store images.

After uploading (submitting the form), I get this with the `print_r($FILES)` function:

`Array ( [Image] => Array ( [name] => 4HfoEtn.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php151F.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 70107 ) )`

However, when navigating to C:\Windows\Temp\ in my file browser, the file does not exist.

Furthermore, when I run:

```
$tmp_image_dir = basename($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name']);
echo "<img src=\"" . $tmp_image_dir . "\">" . "<br>";
```

No image shows up.

Also, when I run:

```
$image_dir = "/images/";
$image_dir = $image_dir . basename($_FILES['Image']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'], $image_dir)) echo "Image Uploaded Successfully" . "<br>";
```

I do not get a readout of "Image Uploaded Successfully"

Then, pretty obviously, when I run:

```
echo "<img src=\"" . $image_dir . "\">" . "<br>
```

I also get an image placeholder with no image.

Comment: `temp` is just a temporary storage of your uploaded file(in this case) so, you have to migrate that file to another directory, in-order to see/save it.

Comment: Why do you tag all your upload questions with mysql and mysqli?

Comment: It's using a mysql database and I'm using mysqli commands.

Comment: That makes sense, php Nఠ_ఠbie. I know it's temporary. However, the second to last bit of code also doesn't work (no file transfer occurs). This entire thing is all in one script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `$image_dir` exists, if not create it with `mkdir` or manually.
You dont need to use `basename` in `$_FILES["Image"]["name"]` since its already the basename of file.

Try below code

```
<?php
  $image_dir  = "images/";
  if ( !file_exists( $image_dir ) ) {
    mkdir( $image_dir, 0755 );
  }
  $image_dir  = $image_dir.$_FILES["Image"]["name"];
  if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["Image"]["tmp_name"], $image_dir ) ) {
    echo "Image Uploaded Successfully<br>";
  }
  echo '<img src="'.$image_dir.'">';
?>
```

Comment: Running `echo $img_dir` gives /images/4HfoEtn.jpg, so the directory is set. There is an /images/ directory in folder where the site is hosted. With that bit of code, I got an "Image Uploaded Successfully" readout, but the image does not display and there is no image in /images/.

Comment: is that `images` directory is in the same folder where your script contains?

Comment: Yes, it is in the same folder.

Comment: then try using `"images/"` instead of `"/images/"`

Comment: "/" infront of that "images" refers to the root directory, check your server root directory, there must be a folder named "images" and an image file in it ;)

Comment: Yep, you're right. I found it. Very inconvenient location for it.